# css - jQuery using inline style of one element onto another, can do it using the class value but need to use the inline value

Tags: jquery, css, inline

Here is my code

```
      var test = jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").css("height");
      jQuery('#main-home').css({ top: test.height() });
```

The Above does not work since the variable has .css("height"); in it, it works when I remove that and it looks like this

```
      var test = jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container");
      jQuery('#main-home').css({ top: test.height() });
```

It returns top: 0; Since the height is not defined in the stylesheet.

If I run the code below, it returns the inline style of .ls-wp-fullwidth-container

```
      jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").css("height");
      alert(jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").css("height"));
```

I know there is just a little tweak to be made, but I am not sure what.

If I go into my stylesheet and add the height to the class .ls-wp-fullwidth-container then using the first bit of code works perfect.. but I need to return the inline value though..

Comment: Have you tried just using .height() var test = jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container").height();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var test = jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container");

var height = test.css("height");

// You can check the height here
alert(height);

jQuery('#main-home').css({ top: height });

// Also in place of css use .offset()
jQuery('#main-home').offset({ top: height });
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited that part, that bit returns 0, since the height is not defined in the css, but inline

Comment: Maybe because the layerslider takes a few seconds to load, and it does not have an inline style defined on load... because for the ALERT to return 450px the height which is set (its dynamic) i Have to set a time out

Comment: So maybe I can work in a timeout somehow, to load the layersliders height after the plugin loads?

Comment: Ok let me see If I can add a timeout here.. I am open to suggestions on how to write that properly..

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
      var test = jQuery(".ls-wp-fullwidth-container");
          jQuery('#main-home').css({ top: test.height() });
}, 5000);

Comment: I am not sure if there is possibly a better way to go about it.. What about setting it after an element loads

Comment: Dont have to set a timeout with it, and it actually solves my next problem was that I needed to take the height of the slider and subtract by 75px.. but with the .offset it does it for me

Comment: Great to have a helping hand, it can be tough doing things on your own.. is there a + or thanks button?

Comment: You too. Have a nice ahead!